# How to access a drive file metadata universally?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

When I tried to access a file metadata using file id from a java client api, with some user consent, and that user don't have any relationship with that file, I got file not found exception.

But as per my business case, I need to access at-least file permissions from any user consent or without consent. So can some one  help in this directions.

Comment: You cant access private data with out consent.   If the user you are using doesn't have access

Comment: If the file is [shared](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app) anonymously - choose "Anyone with link" option - then any user logged in to Google should be able to access it.